# Creating metadata in zipped file geodatabase using FME

Tags: fme-form, file-geodatabase, metadata

I have a workbench set up where I create a Feature Class inside a file geodatabase. the next step is to create the metadata and load it into the same Feature Class.  This all works fine.

I'm doing the exact same thing with a zipped file geodatabase and it's giving me errors.

`Attempting to create table 'XXXXXXX' with 'geodb_type' set to 'geodb_metadata'. FME features of 'geodb_metadata' can only be written to existing tables. If intending to write metadata, please ensure the table already exists.  If intending to create a new table, ensure the 'geodb_type' is set to a valid table type.
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details`

I've checked all my parameters and they are the same between my zipped and non-zipped file geodatabase.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: See http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Writing-Metadata-to-Geodatabase

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz but I've already done that.

Comment: Which Version of FME?  Which Geodatabase Writer are you using?  Have you selected the "zip output" button on your writer?

Comment: @Fezter it's FME 2014 sp2 with the "Esri Geodatabase (File Geodb ArcObjects)" writer, which I believe isthe only writer that can do metadata.  And yes I've selected the zip output.

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS installed on the same computer to access the ArcObject library?

Comment: @Mapperz  yes ArcGIS 10.1 with FME ESRI Edition and they are integrated.

Comment: @Mapperz and @Fezter I`m at a lost..  I`ve recreated the workbench several time, split it into several workbench but still no luck. Thanks for your help

Comment: One other thing to check, are you running the 64-bit version of FME?  If so, writing to a geodatabase using the ArcObjects writer won't work as ArcGIS is still 32-bit.  Try the 32-bit version of FME and see if you have any luck.

Comment: @Fezter  It's a 32bit install since it's integrated with ArcGIS

Comment: That's what I figured, but I thought I'd check anyway.